# php how to short a string?

Tags: php, function, decode, encode

My question is i have few parameters in the url like

```
mydomain.com/page.php?id=xe455144s&t=nameofpage&s=yt
```

now i want to convert this part of the url -

```
 page.php?id=xe455144s&t=nameofpage&s=yt
```

into a short / encoded and single line url like

```
 mydomain.com/kid55e4s554e4s5   [this is what i imagined]
```

I know how to use .htaccess for url rewrite but what i do not know that is how to make a short numeric or alphanumeric string of the url.

I need to convert if back into a normal string to retrieve the values of the url.

I know about base64_encode / decode but this function make huge url, i need a short one.

Is there any function exists in the php library ?

Purpose - I want to make short URLs for my website for seo purpose and also want to set few parameters into those urls which should be hidden from everyone

please help,

Comment: What is the purpose of that? I didn't get you...Are you talking about URL shortener?

Comment: I want to make short URLs for my website for seo purpose and also want to set few parameters into those urls which should be hidden from everyone. @bob

Comment: Does that mean that _kid55e4s554e4s5_ could be anything else? Just like  _magicxyz_?

Comment: yep ! but i must be able to convert it back to original format so i can retrieve the values from the parameters. @bob

Comment: Then create a unique id for each url, store url and uniqueid in DB and check for the match

Comment: Is there no function available like base64_encode / decode for the same purpose ? i can do the with base64_encode / decode but the issue with base64_encode / decode is, it gives huge length string, and i need short one ! @bob

Comment: Since you want a secret or hidden information you don't need base64 because every one is able to convert and see what is  there

Comment: what if i say i can avoid secrecy condition ? dont want to use database. @bob

Comment: _i can avoid secrecy condition_ You can't by using base64 ;) Use DB solution.

Comment: You do not explicitely need to use a DB. You can do the same with files containing a JSON string or serialized array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use base64 encode in url format [WIKI Base64 RFC4648](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#RFC_4648)

For example:

```
 class Base64Url
 {
    /**
     * It`s base64_encode, but used
     *   - instead +
     *   _ instead /
     * and it does not contain =
     *
     * @param string $input
     * @return string
     */
    public static function encode($input)
    {
        $str = strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/', '-_');
        $str = str_replace('=', '', $str);

        return $str;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $input
     * @return string
     */
    public static function decode($input)
    {
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
    }
}
```

But the use of any method of coding does not shorten your url address.

If we need generate short url - you can create "map".
For example you generate hash "Wqwr42S" and write in your storage "Wqwe42S it is /bla-bla-bla"

Comment: what if i ask you a simple thing, i have a long string and somehow someway i want to short it and then get it back to normal,, that's all i want without using db, @maxim-tkach

Comment: you can not compres 100 bytes string to 5 bytes without save in cache or DB (you can use Redis, this is fast method).

Comment: For example you can try gzcompress, but it good work on very-long text (1000 byte to ~748 byte)